# Can we use Firebase just for Token management

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Can we use firebase just to handle token management? And do authentication and user management in the traditional way.

I want to know the pros and cons of using firebase just for token management.

What is suggested when I want to have the users saved in the MYSQL database and use firebase for authentication?

All your inputs/suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

Firebase provides such flexibility with a custom authentication system.

By modifying your authentication server, a custom signed tokens will be produced when a user successfully signs in. Your app receives this token and uses it to authenticate with Firebase.

The pros:

1. You have a copy of the data in your server, where you can manage/manipulate on your side.  Even though Google has shut down its operation, you still have the user data, access token etc...

Cons:

1. Your server might not scale, slow which lead to bad user experience
   Let's say you are using Javascript, you can achieve this by:
2. Add Firebase to your JavaScript project.
3. Get your project's server keys:

   **a.** Go to the Service Accounts page in your project's settings.

   **b.** Click Generate New Private Key at the bottom of the Firebase Admin SDK section of the Service Accounts page.

   **c.** The new service account's public/private key pair is automatically saved on your computer. Copy this file to your authentication server.
4. Authenticate with Firebase

   **a.** When users sign in to your app, send their sign-in credentials (for example, their username and password) to your authentication server. Your server checks the credentials and returns a custom token if they are valid.

   **b.** After you receive the custom token from your authentication server, pass it to `signInWithCustomToken` to sign in the user:

   ```
   firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
    });
   ```

> After a user signs in for the first time, a new user account is
>   created and linked to the credentials—that is, the user name and
>   password, phone number, or auth provider information—the user signed
>   in with. This new account is stored as part of your Firebase project,
>   and can be used to identify a user across every app in your project,
>   regardless of how the user signs in.

For more details on the implementation, you can search for 
[**Authenticate with Firebase in JavaScript Using a Custom Authentication System**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that is to get the user id from from Firebase and then store it to your MuSQL database.

I already done that before and it worked well with me.